# converting unicode \u sequence (like \u041a) to normal utf-8 text in php

Tags: php, javascript, utf-8, json

I have a string like this
"\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431 Test";

It was decoded by json_encode(), the original string was "Клуб Test" in russian.
when I put it to js like

alert("\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431 Test");

I get correct displaying, like on the screen. So js 
in some way poperly decodes it to normal view.
The question is how can I do the same thing in php, is there any built in method?

[image]

```
THE ANSWER IS:
$json_in = '{"testKey":"\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431 Test"}';
$json_out = json_decode($json_in, true);
or
Convert  "\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431" to  "&#x041a;&#x043b;&#x0443;&#x0431;" 
and perform html_entity_decode($str, null, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want HTML entities to print the characters:

- &#1234; for decimal code
- &#x12a; for hex code

Comment: nope, I want "\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431 Test" became "Клуб Test"

Comment: you would have to replace \u by &#x and append a semicolon

Comment: hey, thanks for clarification!
it really works I converted "\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431" to  "&#x041a;&#x043b;&#x0443;&#x0431;" , made html_entity_decode($str, null, 'UTF-8'); and I've got "Клуб"

But can you tell me, should I always use &#x or in some cases just &# ?


&#1234; for decimal code
&#x12a; for hex code

what is decimal code here, when is it used.

But nevertheless thanks, I guess this is the answer!

Comment: sorry should have made that clear in the first place.
use whatever fits better! in this case hex because you have the hex code already

Answer (score 6):

While converting the data, use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as the options

```
echo json_encode($text, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Thanks, I really paid not much attention to the third parameter of json_encode and I'll read aboot them, but my question is about the specific alredy escaped string, for example I can take one debugiing the other site using firebug-XmlHttpRequests. So I need to decode existing not to encode anything

Comment: @QuadroVal, The accepted solution on this post, is not a right way to solve you have. This is a native feature provided by PHP itself, no need extra complication. Decoding also works the same way.

Comment: Well, tell me please the native feature I would be greatful =) Do you say it's json_decode?
But look at the docs http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php there is no JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option in the 4-th param. It's used only in json_encode. As I said I can affect on the way of encoding

Comment: @QuadroVal, There is no need to specify that option, it does it itself. Please try it once.

Comment: Yes you are right, I tried previously but my problem was that I was trying to decode just string (not jsons str), like //$json_in = "\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431 Test"; and not $json_in = '{"testKey":"\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431 Test"}';
$json_out = json_decode($json_in, true); Thanks.